# Add nested hierarchy to end of tel: link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested list item with deep sublevels. For instance:

a

```
a,a
a,b
    a,b,a
    a,b,b
b
    b,a
    b,b
    b,c
    b,d
        b,d,a
        b,d,b
```

The last list is a tel link.
Let's say the tel link for b,d,a is `<li><a class="tel-link" href="tel:8888">b,d,a</a></li>`

How can I track the hierarchy and add the numbered sublevels to the end of the tel link so it becomes `<li><a class="tel-link" href="tel:8888,2,4,1">b,d,a</a></li>` and adds ,2,4,1 to the end of the tel link?

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umutucler/e3ym6zt4/)

Comment: You mean `2,4,1` or `2,4,0`?

Comment: I mean 2,4,1. The first one will always start with 1

Comment: @user1872505 are you wanting to dynamically change the `href` values (say on document.ready)?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to track the numbered level (don't know how to describe it) and concatenate it to the href, in this case `8888` so it will end up having the ordered sublevel so it becomes `8888,2,4,1`.

Comment: And if it was a,b,a the href would be concatenated with 1,2,1 so it goes from `8888` to `8888,1,2,1`

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `.index()` function (see the docs, https://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

I've put together a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xegnfqon/)** to demonstrate.

The highlight is a recursive function:

```
function getAncestory(el)
{
    if (el.parent().parent().is("li"))
        // If this <li> element is a child, prepend the parent indices
        return getAncestory(el.parent().parent()) + "," + el.index();
    else
        return el.index()
}

// Only register clicks on <li> elements that don't have children
// (there are other ways to do an equivalent selector)
$("li:not(:has(*))").click(function(event){
    alert(getAncestory($(this)))
})
```

This fiddle returns your `desired_result - 1`. I've left it like that because it's trivial to increment all the values by `1` but it's simpler to understand the code without the increment.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still in the first phase of learning jQuery and will try to see if I can make it work. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask about the code in question.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get my head around three things. 1: This should be done in the div called #menu and look for list element in that div. 2. I tried every ways I usually increment by one but without luck. 3. I'm not sure how to concatenate it to the tel link (in this example, 8888) so it end up being e.g. 8888,2,4,1